# Why is my array throwing an error "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" when I use array.Length as index?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm using `StringBuilder` to replace each character in a string by using an int that gets converted to a char. For some reason, the string builder throws an "Out of index error" even if the index is inside of the range.

I want to use I as the index but I changed it to `array.Length` just to make sure the index was in range.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

char[] array = input.ToCharArray();

int totalOffsetToRemove = array.Length + 44;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);

string result;

for (int i = array.Length; i > 0; i--)
{
    char c = Convert.ToChar(totalOffsetToRemove);                    
    sb[array.Length] = c;

    result = sb.ToString();                  
    Console.WriteLine(result);

    totalOffsetToRemove -= 2;
}
```

Comment: Because of zero indexing (count it out)!

Comment: `int i = array.Length` .... is out of range.... try `int i = array.Length - 1`!

Comment: Because string lengths are also zero-indexed. Example: we can agree `"hello"` is length 5. `"hello"[0] => 'h'`.. `"hello"[4] => 'o'` .. `"hello"[5] => crash`.

Comment: You should also change `i > 0`  ... to  ... `i >= 0`  ... or you will miss the first item in the array.

Comment: Because arrays are zero-indexed. That means that if you have an array with length = 5, then the valid indexes are 0 through 4 (or better, 0 through length - 1). If you learn to use the debugger, you can figure out these sorts of issue yourself.

Comment: `but didn't know .Length was 1 indexed` What do you mean by this? `Length` is the length of the entity, as per the docs. It matters not whether it is 1 indexed or 0 indexed or anything else - the `Length` is the length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Comment: Why would you use `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop since you never use `i`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes start with zero, so array[array.Length] is not valid and index is ranged from `0` to `array.Length - 1`.

change

```
for (int i = array.Length; i > 0; i--)
```

to

```
for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```